# Laravel delete subquery

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I need to perform a delete operation which includes a subquery. It goes something like this:

`delete from images where exists ( select thumbnail from posts where posts.id = 10 )`

How do I do this with the [whereExists function](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#deletes)? I'm trying to pass in the integer value dynamically by a variable, but its throwing an error saying the variable isn't defined.
The variable is not getting detected inside the closure. HOw can I do that?

**Note:** The *10* in the query is a value that in passed in by php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
$postId = Input::get('postId');

DB::table('posts')
    ->whereExists(function($query) use ($postId) {
       // now you have $query and $postId
        $query->select('thumbnail')
              ->from('posts')
              ->where('id', '=', $postId);
    })->delete();
```

PS: It seems weird to use `EXISTS` with the same table. Can't you simplify to something like this (?):

```
delete from posts where posts.thumbnail is not null and posts.id = 10
```

Comment: smooooth! That worked. :D

Why isn't the `use` keyword used anywhere in the Laravel docs? Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: Whoops! the table should've been images. Doh!

Comment: @maxxon15, `use` is not referred in Laravel's documentation because it's native from PHP closures. Laravel is just leveraging this. To know more about closures visithttp://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php